# Jquery - vertically center div only works when resizing the window

Tags: jquery, centering, window-resize, outerheight

I have some Divs that appears when you click on certain links. The divs with the class name "position-center" vertical centers on the screen. But the thing is that the divs is offset the center on load until you resize the window.

I tried to search the question database but I can't seem to find the solution to the problem.

The Javascript code for centering and showing the divs:

```
onResize = function() {
        var topPos = ($(window).height() - $('.position-center').outerHeight())/2;
        $('.position-center').css({
            top: topPos > 0 ? topPos : 0
        });
    };
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(onResize);
        $(window).resize(onResize);
        $(".modal-button").click(function(){
            $("divs:visible").hide();
            $("#"+$(this).attr("data-showdiv")).show();
        });
        $('.abort').click(function() {
            $("div.modal-background").hide();
        });
    });
```

HTML for one of the Divs

```
 <div class="modal-background" id="modal-1">
    <div class="modal-window">
        <div class="modal-content position-center">
            <span class="title">Modal #2</span>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <a href="#" class="button abort"><span>Abort</span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The link for calling the divs:

```
<a class="modal-button" data-showdiv="modal-1" href="#"><span>SHOW DIV</span></a>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Just put `onResize()` on the line after `.show()`

Comment: Archer is correct, you should also remove `$(onResize);` this is not how you call a function but instead tries to convert it into a jquery object.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm... except it doesnt center properly in Chrome. Is this is know issue?

Comment: Yes, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268892/outerheighttrue-gives-wrong-value

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that only Div #1 is centering perfect, the other ones have slight offset that increases. Div #6 has more offset than Div#2 and so on. Does anyone have a theory of this is possible?