# jQuery OuterHeight/Height return the wrong height value when height is auto

Tags: jquery, css

How do I get the full height of a div object filled with text when the CSS height is set to Auto?

I tried OuterHeight and it still is not the full height of the div object.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zerolfc/jg8s5oq3/3/

jQuery:

```
$('div').find('*').each(function(ti,tv){
var c = parseInt( $(tv).css('font-size') ) / 2;
c = Math.floor( c );
c = ( c < 8 ? 8 : c );
$(tv).css('font-size', c + 'px');
});

console.log($('div').outerHeight(true));
```

CSS:

```
div { display: block; width: 640px; height: auto; }
p { font-size: 24px; }
```

HTML:

```
<div>
<p>This is a textbox that you can add text to suit your design and alter.This is a textbox that you can add text to suit your design and alter.</p>
<p>This is a textbox that you can add text to suit your design and alter.This is a textbox that you can add text to suit your design and alter.</p>
<p>This is a textbox that you can add text to suit your design and alter.This is a textbox that you can add text to suit your design and alter.</p>
<p>This is a textbox that you can add text to suit your design and alter.This is a textbox that you can add text to suit your design and alter.</p><p>This is a textbox that you can add text to suit your design and alter.This is a textbox that you can add text to suit your design and alter.</p><p>This is a textbox that you can add text to suit your design and alter.This is a textbox that you can add text to suit your design and alter.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Returns the right value in the fiddle for me.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/AXATT

Comment: In the console window I get the same 228px as you get but 252px when inspecting the div it returns the height ( dimensions tooltip ) of 252px in Chrome?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268892/outerheighttrue-gives-wrong-value/47036074 for a similar question.

Answer (score 1):

Returns right values in fiddle for me.

From http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/

```
$('div').outerHeight(true) = [height of the $('div') + margin of $('div')]
```

but your `$('div')` element doesnt have any margin as per your current css rules.

Which means,
`$('div').outerHeight(true)` is going to return you the actual height of the `$('div')` without any margins.

In your case, value of all following 3 is going to be same.

- `$('div').outerHeight(true)`
- `$('div').outerHeight()`
- `$('div').css('height')`